# Sequelize | Node.js, search between two numbers

Tags: node.js, search, sequelize.js

I'm working on an advanced search with multiple options with Sequelize and Node.js.
One of the options is between two prices.

```
  const search2 = req.body.search2;
  const title = req.body.title;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const prices = req.body.prices;
  const prices2 = req.body.prices2;
  const address = req.body.address;

Product.findAll({
    where: { [Op.and]:
 { price: { [Op.like]: '%' + price + '%' },
 category: { [Op.like]: '%' + title + '%' },
 description: { [Op.like]: '%' + search2 + '%' },
 Renting: { [Op.between]: [prices, prices2] },
 address: { [Op.like]: '%' + address + '%' } } }
    , order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']], limit, offset
  })
```

`const prices` and `const prices2` are two inputs which the user can write the min and max price.

In my Sequelize model I have column 'Renting' (for renting prices, its INTEGER).
it seems to be that everything is working fine,but the problem is that i get the between prices and prices2 '50' AND '200'. (for example if im searching between 50 and 200).
[enter image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5PKD.jpg)
which is giving me empty results or wrong results for different numbers.
I noticed if i put numbers beside prices and prices2, for example i will write: 
Renting: { [Op.between]: [50, 200] },
i will get the right results. 50 AND 200 (without '')
[enter image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKvPO.jpg)
which is good. But it just if I defined the numbers by myself.

Can anyone please help me to find a solution how to get the right result using this two inputs (prices and prices2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should convert `prices` and `prices2` to INTEGER before use it in query, and you can update your code

```
Renting: { [Op.between]: (+prices, +prices2) },
```

because when you putting '50' , '250' can not match it and return wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor modification to @mohammad javad ahmadi's answer:

```
Renting: { [Op.between]: [+prices, +prices2] },
```

Op.between expects array, not tuple.